# $B(R,R)$ is not closed in the topology of compact convergence

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I'm doing this exercise in Munkres book, and got no clue to solve this problem. Help someone can help me.

> > Let $B(R,R)$ be the set of bounded functions $f: R \rightarrow R$. Prove that $B(R,R)$ is not closed in the topology of compact convergence

Thanks

Comment: Take an unbounded (continuous, to make things easy) function $f$, and show that there is a sequence of bounded (continuous, or not) functions that converges compactly to $f$.

Comment: I know how to prove it's not closed. But the problem is what the specific sequence is?

Comment: Any continuous function is bounded on every compact set, so just choose any sequence $f_n$ such that $f_n$ coincides with $f$ on $[-n,n]$ and is bounded.

Comment: Got it. Thanks...\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $f(x)=x^2$, say. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $f_n(x)=\min\{x^2,n\}$.